# Deferred deep links always null in android and facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, deferred, deep-linking

I'm having a problem with the deferred deep links https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking#deferred-deep-linking with facebook android sdk v4.8.1. It always returns null for the applink data on the callback of fetchDeferredAppLink method. I've tested with this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/ with the deferred checkbox enabled and uninstalling the app and reintalling both from playstore and android studio. I am logged in with my account on facebook on my phone. I've double checked that the setup is right, and I can't imagine what the problem or error might be.

Comment: I would recommend you [file a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) with repro steps and a sample project

Comment: We have the same problem, there is a fresh bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/590178251129170/

Comment: We filled a bug report and got it confirmed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1952666988291053/

Comment: Already did that: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1952666988291053/

Answer (score 0):

While Facebook gets their bug fixed, I recommend taking a look at [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) and their ability to link to your app from a Facebook Ad via deferred deeplinking. The solution works well for Branch links shared to a user's status as well.

I have used their links in my own Android application, more specifically for ads and I've noticed that they can track Installs and Opens very well.

Comment: Yeap, we were already using branch. Thanks for the tip anyway.