# Facebook unity GetAppLink CallBack does not have target url

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, deeplink

I am using Facebook Unity SDK v7.4.0 with FBAndroidSDK/4.8.2 and managed to implement deep link in a unity game for android platform. Clicking on the deep link  takes me inside the game. Now I want that when the user enters the game, he has to be rewarded. But the GetAppLink callback does not have target url

```
    Facebook.Unity.FB.GetAppLink(DeepLinkCallback);

    void DeepLinkCallback(IAppLinkResult result) 
    { 
       if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty (result.TargetUrl)) 
       {
       }
       else
       {
           Debug.Log("result is null");
       }
    }
```

I have gone through many links to try solving this.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.GetAppLink
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1134007/how-to-get-facebook-game-request-url.html
[Deferred deep links always null in android and facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313449/deferred-deep-links-always-null-in-android-and-facebook-sdk)

Also deep link is enabled in the developer site, also checked if Facebook sdk is initialised properly before getting the callback

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the targetUrl but to reward the user you just have to check result.url as mentioned in [the FB.GetAppLink documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.GetAppLink).

```
FB.GetAppLink(DeepLinkCallback);

void DeepLinkCallback(IAppLinkResult result) {
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Url)) {
        var index = (new Uri(result.Url)).Query.IndexOf("request_ids");
        if(index != -1) {
            **// ...have the user interact with the friend who sent the request,
            // perhaps by showing them the gift they were given, taking them
            // to their turn in the game with that friend, etc.**
        }
    }
}
```

To send custom data through a Facebook app request, you need to add that data — for example details of your gift — in the [FB.AppRequest as mentioned in its documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.AppRequest).

You need to get the last request id from the URL in the deep link call back and then call Facebook API to get your gift data out of it.

```
FB.API ("/" + recievedRequestId, HttpMethod.GET, CallbackFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

result.url will be null if you haven't added a scheme in Facebook SDK's unity settings.

com.example.appname is probably what you are looking to add.

[image]